# How to create stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to create stored procedure for this c# statement

```
String Orders = "INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('" + DDLCustomerID.SelectedValue + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtNetPrice.Text) + "');" + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Orders, Connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Connection.Open();
int intID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

String Orderdetails1 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct1.SelectedItem + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice1.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity1.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice1.Text) + "')";
SqlCommand Command1 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails1, Connection);
Command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

String Orderdetails2 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct2.SelectedItem + " ','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice2.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity2.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice2.Text) + "')";
SqlCommand Command2 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails2, Connection);
Command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

String Orderdetails3 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct3.SelectedItem + " ','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice3.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity3.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice3.Text) + "')";
SqlCommand Command3 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails3, Connection);
Command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully Inserted');</script>");
Connection.Close();
```

How to create stored procedure for this c# statement
The table I created in SQL SERVER is

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
     CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     FirstName  NVARCHAR(45),
     LastName   NVARCHAR(45),
     Address    NVARCHAR(45)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
    TotalPrice  INT
)

CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
(
    OrderID     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
    ProductName NVARCHAR(45),
    Quantity    NVARCHAR(45),
    Price       NVARCHAR(45),
    TotalPrice  INT
)
```

I want to create a stored procedure for this statement

Comment: DO YOU NEED SQl part of the syntax

Comment: Yes I want SQL part Syntax @HardikParmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SQL code that you need to write :

Syntax for stored procedure :

```
Create Proc Proc_Name
(
  @PARAM1 DATATYPE,
  ....
)
AS
BEGIN
   BODY OF THE SP
END
```

This is the way to create the stored procedure in SQL.
As you have bunch of queries that you are executing at the single shot.
You also tack care of your transaction.
If suppose your last insert query got `EXCEPTION` then you above all the queries needs to be rollback & not should be executed.
I have also done rollback in the stored procedure.

```
    CREATE PROC Procedure_Name
(
    @Customer_id INT,
    @TxtNetPrice FLOAT,
    @DDLProduct1 INT,
    @TxtQuantity1 FLOAT,
    @TxtTotalPrice1 FLOAT,
    @TxtPrice1 FLOAT,
    @intID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON


    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(@Customer_id,@TxtNetPrice)
        DECLARE @S_ID int;
        SET @S_ID  = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

        INSERT INTO 
            OrderDetails 
        VALUES(@intID,@DDLProduct1,@TxtPrice1,@TxtQuantity1,@TxtTotalPrice1)

    COMMIT
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 

              DECLARE @ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR(MAX), @SEVERITY INT, @STATE INT
              SELECT @SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @STATE = ERROR_STATE()
              , @ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' err src line: ' + CAST( ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '');           
               --@ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                ROLLBACK;
             -- RE-THROW EXCEPTION FOR DIAGNOSTIC VISIBILITY
              RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG ,@SEVERITY, @STATE);        
              RETURN

    END CATCH   

END
```

Comment: I want OrderID to  display in 'OrderDetails' Table from 'Order' Table @HardikParmar

Comment: @jabi Means You need order back from this stored procedure & want to display Order Details table am i Right

Comment: It is showing error @HardikParamar                                   Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Orderssp, Line 37
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "orderid_ref". The conflict occurred in database "CustomersOrders", table "dbo.Orders", column 'OrderID'. err src line: 22 Orderssp

Comment: Yes I want OrderId to Show back in Orderdetails @HardikParmar